# Como substituir/replace chaves de array

Tags: javascript

Tenho 2 array's (um que armazena valores de uma 'pessoa' e outro que armazena as 'keys/propriedades' relativos a esta pessoa) e gostaria de substituir as chaves de 1 desses array para colocar como chave no outro `array`, da seguinte forma:

```
let dataHead = ['nome', 'segundoNome', 'priSobrenome', 'segSobrenome'];
let dataBody = [
    { '0': 'Ikaro', '1': 'Fernando', '2': 'Sales dos', '3': 'Santos' },
    { '0': 'Ana', '1': 'Carolina', '2': 'Sales dos', '3': 'Santos' }
];
```

E gostaria que com a junção desses arrays ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
// 'nome': 'Ikaro', 'segundoNome': 'Fernando', 'priSobrenome': 'Sales dos', 'segSobrenome': 'Santos'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta percorrer seu array de chaves e ir adicionando cada chave e valor em um novo objeto. Dessa forma:

```js
let dataHead = ['nome', 'segundoNome', 'priSobrenome', 'segSobrenome'];
let dataBody = {'0': 'Ikaro', '1': 'Fernando', '2': 'Sales dos', '3': 'Santos'}

var novoObj = {};

for (i = 0; i < dataHead.length; i++){
    novoObj[dataHead[i]] = dataBody[i];
}

console.log(novoObj);
```

Comment: Mas aí vc mudou o tipo de **dataBody** man!

Comment: O dataBody dele não fazia muito sentido, até porque o resultado final que ele queria era com os valores do primeiro objeto. O que eu fiz foi só dar uma simplificada, mas se ele quiser usar aquele dataBody, basta colocar o index **0** na frente de **[i]**.